# Pandas datetime conversion issue

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

got confused while converting a pandas column of timestamps to 'month'. I have a series of datetime and i'm just interested to extract the month. Got the following awkward result.

## max timestamp

> a = (df[df['sr_process_year'] == 2019]['sr_open_date']).max()

a = 2019-08-23 20:59:12

## datetime conversion

> b = a.month

b = 8

## Pandas .dt.month conversion

> c = (df[df['sr_process_year'] == 2019]['sr_open_date']).dt.month

c.max() = 12 !!??

I would highly appreciate to get your comments why .dt.month method does provide inaccurate outcome. Thxs !

Comment: Can you share data?

Comment: What happens if you take the `min` on the date `(df[df['sr_process_year'] == 2019]['sr_open_date']).min()`? I bet it is before 2019.

Comment: I'm creating and trying a dataframe and it sounds normal, so can I see your data?

Comment: What is the relation between `'sr_process_year'` and `'sr_open_date'`?

Comment: replacing max() by min provides a comparable issue.  min timestamp = 2016-09-27 01:15:22 / month_b = 9 / month_c = 1 !!

Comment: Ok, so newest date is in 2019, oldest is in 2016. There are probably dates in January and December between them, which would make the maximum and minimum of the dates 12 and 1 respectively.

Comment: To find it, you may try `df[(df['sr_process_year'] == 2019) & (df['sr_open_date'].dt.month == 12)]`

Comment: I've done some dataset cleaning and solved the issue. Some records were corrupted with wrong 'sr_process_year' information ! Thank you all for your feedback/comments.